# Ingress is healthchecking readiness probe every few seconds

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

My Ingress, Service and Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: my-certificate
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-api-nodeport
    servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-api-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 43200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api-nodeport
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"my-api-backendconfig"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-api
          image: gcr.io/acme/api
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /readinessProbe
              port: 80
          env:
            ...
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
```

According to GKE UI, the Ingress healthcheck interval is 70 sec. However in practice I see lots of logs in my deployment to the readiness probe, about every couple of seconds.

```
2019-12-08 08:42:11 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.16.62.83:80/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:11 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.1037ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:16 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.15.222/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:16 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.11610000000000001ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:18 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.15.222/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:18 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.10880000000000001ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:19 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.15.222/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:19 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.10790000000000001ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:21 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.16.62.83:80/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:21 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.14730000000000001ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:27 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.0.23/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:27 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.12040000000000001ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:27 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.0.23/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:27 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.1153ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:28 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.0.23/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:28 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.1563ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:31 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.16.62.83:80/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:31 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.11900000000000001ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:36 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.15.195/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:36 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.113ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:36 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.15.195/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:36 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.1153ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:38 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.128.15.195/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:38 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.1208ms 200
2019-12-08 08:42:41 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.16.62.83:80/readinessProbe
2019-12-08 08:42:41 [INFO] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 0.10600000000000001ms 200
```

Can I configure the interval to a lower rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure readiness probes as below

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
```

Please refer to the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/ for further help.

Comment: also note that a health check is sent for every node in the cluster, even though you only have 1 pod On top of that, the GCE health check will be sent from multiple sources across multiple regions, so for every check per node, there are multiple checks sent from multiple regions. This tends to result in a much greater number of health checks than expected Lowering the `periodSeconds` will decrease the frequency, but continue to expect this burst of checks at the interval